# Union and Count Collections in Neo4j

Tags: collections, neo4j, cypher, union, intersection

My simple database contains nodes of 'terms' and 'codes' linked to each other.
There are two types of relationships.

Relationships between 'terms' and 'codes' called :CODE and are undirected (or read in both directions equally).
Relationships between 'terms' called :NT (which means narrow term) and are directed.

I want to walk thru all the 'terms' from top to bottom and collect all the unique codes and count them.

This is my query:

```
MATCH (a)-[:NT*]->(b), (a)-[:CODE]-(c), (b)-[:CODE]-(d)
WHERE a.btqty = 0
RETURN a.termid AS termid, a.maxlen AS maxlen, COUNT(DISTINCT c.code) + COUNT(DISTINCT d.code) AS total, COLLECT(DISTINCT c.code) + COLLECT(DISTINCT d.code) AS codes
ORDER BY termid;
```

This is what I get:

```
termid  maxlen  total   codes
22  2   3   ["S70","S43","S70"]
25  4   9   ["S20","S21","S54","S61","S63","S63","S21","S61","S54"]
26  2   9   ["S99","S98","S29","S13","S13","S20","S29","S14","S15"]
68  5   13  ["S38","S11","S12","S11","S12","S38","S37","S21","S36","S22","S98","S63","S58"]
123 2   3   ["S38","S12","S12"]
154 2   2   ["S58","S58"]
155 4   3   ["S63","S62","S63"]
159 2   2   ["S36","S36"]
...
```

I need to get rid of duplicates in collection and count them properly like this:

```
termid  maxlen  total   codes
22  2   2   ["S43","S70"]
25  4   5   ["S20","S21","S54","S61","S63"]
26  2   7   ["S99","S98","S29","S13","S20","S14","S15"]
68  5   10  ["S38","S11","S12","S37","S21","S36","S22","S98","S63","S58"]
123 2   2   ["S38","S12"]
154 2   1   ["S58"]
155 4   2   ["S63","S62"]
159 2   1   ["S36"]
...
```

I think this is something about REDUCE function to apply but I do not know how to use it.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, this can be solved using `REDUCE`. Inside the reduce you need to check if the current element already exists in the accumulator and conditionally amend it:

```
MATCH (a)-[:NT*]->(b), (a)-[:CODE]-(c), (b)-[:CODE]-(d)
WHERE a.btqty = 0
WITH a.termid AS termid, a.maxlen AS maxlen, 
   REDUCE(uniqueCodes=[], 
         x in COLLECT(DISTINCT c.code) + COLLECT(DISTINCT d.code) |
          CASE WHEN x IN uniqueCodes THEN uniqueCodes ELSE uniqueCodes+x END
   ) AS codes
ORDER BY termid
RETURN termid, maxlen, count(codes) as total, codes
```

Comment: Many thanks! Now I've got the idea how REDUCE works. By the way, it goes like LENGTH(codes) AS total to count(codes). Thank you so much!!!